# How to create a data frame out of a deeply nested list of lists that contains data frames as well?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

I work with data from TMDb that I got with help from the API and R. The output is one list containing n-lists that contain data frames themselves. I can't work with nested lists and prefer just one data frame.

It feels like I've tried everything, but nothing works.

Reproducable Code for my ugly list (imagine this list has over 400.000 lists itself):

```
genres <- data.frame("id" = as.integer(c(35, 40)), "name" = c('Horror','Comedy'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cast <- data.frame("id" = as.integer(c(1, 2)), "name" = c("Bruce Willis", "Demi Moore"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

crew <- data.frame("job" = c("Director", "Producer", "Screenwriter"), "id" = as.integer(c(1,2,3)), "name" = c("Steven Spielberg", "Peter Pan", "Arnold Schwarzenegger"), "gender" = as.integer(c(0,0,0)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

genres2 <- data.frame("id" = as.integer(c(42, 43)), "name" = c("Drama","Lovestory"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cast2 <- data.frame("id" = as.integer(c(3, 4)), "name" = c("Johnny Depp", "Leonardo Di Caprio"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

crew2 <- data.frame("job" = c("Director", "Producer", "Producer", "Screenwriter"),"id" = as.integer(c(1,6,7,8)), "name" = c("Steven Spielberg", "Dumbo", "Cinderella", "Micky Mouse"), "gender" = as.integer(c(0,0,1,0)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

genres3 <- data.frame("id" = as.integer(c(35, 42)), "name" = c("Horror","Drama"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


lst <- list(list("id" = as.integer(601), 
                  "revenue" = as.integer(15000), 
                  "genre" = genres, 
                  "cast" = list("cast" = cast, "crew" = crew)), 
             list("id" = as.integer(602), 
                  "revenue" = as.integer(20000), 
                  "genre" = genres2, 
                  "cast" = list("cast" = cast2, "crew" = crew2)),
             list("id" = as.integer(603), 
                  "revenue" = as.integer(12000), 
                  "genre" = genres3, 
                  "cast" = list("cast" = list(), "crew" = list())))
```

I just want to flatten this nested list and get 3 data frames out of it. I'm only interested in Producer and Director.

```
df1

id    revenue   genre               Producer            Director
601   15000     Horror, Comedy      Peter Pan           Steven Spielberg
602   20000     Drama, Lovestory    Dumbo, Cinderella   Steven Spielberg
603   12000     Horror, Drama       NA                  NA

df2 - So here I need the collaborations from Producer and Director

id    Producer    Director
601   Peter Pan   Steven Spielberg
602   Dumbo       Steven Spielberg
602   Cinderella  Steven Spielberg

df3 - Only information about people

Name              Gender    ID
Peter Pan         0         2 
Steven Spielberg  0         1
Cinderella        1         7
.
.
.
```

I hope you can help me in any kind of way. I hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is to get a clean dataframe, for that we can use `map_df` to loop through *lst* and create a dataframe. After that you may use `select`, `dplyr::filter`, `tidyr::spread` and `separate_rows` to get df1, df2, df3

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map_df(lst,  
        ~ tibble(id = .x$id, 
                 revenue = .x$revenue, 
                 genre = ifelse(length(.x$genre$name)>1, paste(.x$genre$name, collapse = ','), .x$genre$name), 
                 cast = imap(.x$cast, 
                            ~ if(length(.x$id)==0) data.frame(id1=NA, name=NA, term='crew', job=c("Director", "Producer"), gender=NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) else 
                              data.frame(.x, term=.y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
                ) %>% 
          unnest(cast)
        ) -> df

#df1
df1 <- filter(df, term=='crew' & job %in% c("Director", "Producer")) %>% 
       group_by(id, job) %>% 
       mutate(name= paste(name[!is.na(name)], collapse = ',')) %>%   
       slice(1) %>% dplyr::select(-id1, -term, -gender) %>% 
       spread(key=job, value = name) %>% ungroup()

#df2
separate_rows(df1, Producer, sep = ',')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I looks very good, but the output doesn't quite look like my desired output though

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extremely convoluted way to do what you want. Your desired `df2` is just `df1` with a few columns removed. As for `df3` with the genders, you should be able to access them in a similar way to these functions.

```
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(list,c)))

f_genre <- function(df_input){
    row_num <- c(1:nrow(df_input))
    for (i in row_num){
        temp <- Reduce(merge,df_input$genre[[i]]$name)
        temp_concat <- paste(temp$x,temp$y, sep=", ")
        df_input$genre[[i]] <- temp_concat
        df_final <<- df_input
    }
}


f_producer <- function(df_input)
{
    row_num <- c(1:nrow(df_input))
    for (i in row_num)
    {
        num_jobs <- c(1:length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$job))
        temp_producer_list <- list()
        if (length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew) != 0)
        {
            for (job_num in num_jobs)
            {
                if(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$job[job_num] == "Producer")
                {
                    temp_producer <- df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$name[job_num]
                    temp_producer_list <- c(temp_producer_list, temp_producer)
                    temp_producer_list <- paste(temp_producer_list,collapse=", ")
                }
            }
            df_input$Producer[[i]] <- temp_producer_list
        }
        if (length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew) == 0)
        {
            df_input$Producer[[i]] <- NA
        }
        df_final <<- df_input
    }
}


f_director <- function(df_input)
{
    row_num <- c(1:nrow(df_input))
    for (i in row_num)
    {
        num_jobs <- c(1:length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$job))
        temp_director_list <- list()
        if (length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew) != 0)
        {
            for (job_num in num_jobs)
            {
                if(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$job[job_num] == "Director")
                {
                    temp_director <- df_input$cast[[i]]$crew$name[job_num]
                    temp_director_list <- c(temp_director_list, temp_director)
                    temp_director_list <- paste(temp_director_list,collapse=", ")
                }
            }
            df_input$Director[[i]] <- temp_director_list
        }
        if (length(df_input$cast[[i]]$crew) == 0)
        {
            df_input$Director[[i]] <- NA
        }
        df_final <<- df_input
    }
}



f_genre(df)
f_producer(df_final)
f_director(df_final)

df1 <- df_final[,-4]
```

[image: dframe]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Can't believe it. I hope I can reproduce it on my original crazy list.